# Are forward declarations needed after includes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include, forward-declaration

I have a class called GameState in its own file and that class has a pointer to another object of type StatusView which is in its own file. In GameState.h, I have included the StatusView header but when I try to compile it, I get the error:

```
missing type specifier - int assumed
```

However, when I forward declare StatusView even after including it, I am able to compile it. I have no clue what's causing the requirement to forward declare the class.

Comment: Post the source and an example. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: The error is on line 42.

Comment: How do you know it's on line 42?
I can't quite post a self-contained piece of code, it's part of a huge project I'm working on. Could it be due to circular references, as in the GameState has a pointer to StatusView and StatusView has a pointer to GameState?

Comment: He's kidding.  It's a hint for you to post your source, which will let us give you a proper answer.

To me, it looks like your include isn't declaring the StatusView object properly since the forward declaration works.

Comment: My crystal ball says the problem is that your include guards aren't unique.

Comment: Well, the error was on line 42, that's what threw me off.

Comment: Does the header file where `StatusView` is defined also include `GameState.h`?  If so, you have a circular inclusion, and the only way for that to work successfully is with forward declarations in at least one of the headers.

Comment: See, Douglas Adams was right: 42 really is the answer to life, the universe and everything!

Comment: @Jerry Coffin I always thought 43 is that number, oh well..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a circular dependency between the headers. A includes B and B includes A, but B *doesn't* really include A because `#pragma once` was already evaluated for A. (It would be the same with a standard header guard.)

Because the inner inclusion is ignored, it's as if it were never there at all, and you need the forward declaration.